# Want to get a list of files compiled with make for kernel project

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile

I want to get the list of files compiled for Linux kernel, for two different configs. Hypothetically, If I have same board with different processors, then I want to get the list of files which are common and which are not common.
Its not specific to kernel only, but a generic question. My intent is to obtain
the files, which are getting compiled with make.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no direct way for get this list. However, [format](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) of all `Makefiles` except top-level one is relatively simple, so you can write script which traverses them and collects information required.

Comment: Maybe try `find . -name "*.o" > obj_list.txt` after compiling each config and then diff the list of objects?

Comment: Or wrap your compiler in a simple shell script that logs all of its arguments to a file, and sift through that.   Or tap into your build systems auditing facilities to log each `exec` call to the compiler--this is the hardest way, but I've seen static analysis tools do it.

Comment: What is the actual goal here? What do you want to find out exactly? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Etan Reisner I am compiling my kernel for different boards and want to see all those files touched during compilation of each config. Want to get some stats on the common and varying files under both the compilations. As simple as that.

Comment: The Linux kernel compilation (using the provided Makefiles, of course) prints a lot of information on the standard output. Look at all lines with CC or HOSTCC as first token and you will have your lists: one for the cross-compiled files, the other for the files compiled by the host compiler. Use the V=0|1|2 make flag if needed (see make help).